# Kivy application window does not start

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

The kivy application window does not start, I don’t know what’s the matter. This is the simplest Hello World app, but the window just not appears.
Here is the code in main.py:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()
        
if "__name__" == "__main__":
    FirstApp.run()
```

also in first.kv:

```
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
```

Here are the logs:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 06:20:32) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

It doesn't look like there is any error here.
I use mac os, Catalina, I also tried parallels desktop on a virtual machine (both on Ubuntu and Windows)
Sorry for my English, I'm not from English speaking country.
Help me, please!

Comment: Do you actually have `FirstApp.run()`? That would be wrong, it should be `FirstApp().run()`

Comment: @inclement, yes, I changed it and nothing had changed, maybe there something else can be wrong?

Comment: Post the exact code you're running, and the command you're using to run it.

Comment: @inclement, here is the code from main.py:

```from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()
        
if "__name__" == "__main__":
    FirstApp().run()```
here is the code from first.kv:
```<Container>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello!"
    Button:
        text: "World!"
```

here is the command:

```python3 main.py```

Logs are the same, they are too big for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how should be

```py
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()
# the main reason that your code is not running because you make __name__ as 
# string so this condition will never be true so the app will not load        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FirstApp().run()
```

and for kv file

```py
<Container>:# you miss this line which the root widget
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
```